# Secured controller action shows 401 error instead of redirecting to login page in .NET 7

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, asp.net-authorization

I am developing a .NET 7 Web application that has secured areas.

This is a monolith application, so that it is separated in different assemblies.

So far, the assemblies separation works well, but now I am implementing secured pages.

This is the Startup class of the module:

```
public class Startup : IModuleStartup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>, CustomPasswordHasher>();
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
        {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            options.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128;
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        })
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddTransient<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, CustomUserStore>();
        services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>, CustomRoleStore>();

        services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>();
        services.AddScoped<IUsuarioService, UsuarioService>();
        services.AddDbContext<SecuWebModulesAuthenticateContext>(options =>
        {
            options
                .UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Modules.Authenticate"));
#if DEBUG
            options.LogTo(x => Debug.WriteLine(x));
#endif
        });

        // Agrega autenticación
        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Security/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Security/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Security/AccessDenied";
                options.ReturnUrlParameter = "ReturnUrl";
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:AuthJwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:AuthJwt:Audience"],
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    RequireExpirationTime = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Modules:Authenticate:AuthJwt:Key"] ?? string.Empty))
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

On the other hand, I have this controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class UsuarioController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Well, when I browse to https://localhost:7255/Usuario, this page is shown:

[image]

What configuration is missing here?

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using? `Startup.cs` is no longer used, the services are configured in `Program.cs` (refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-7.0); compare to the [old version of that article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-5.0)).

Comment: It is .NET 7. I used Startup.cs because it is a modular monolith application. The entry application has the Program.cs file. It loads the modules and for each module, it loads their startup. I followed the example here: https://github.com/thinktecture-labs/aspnetcore-modular-monolith/tree/main

Comment: What is `AuthorizeEnumAttribute`, is it something built-in into ASP.NET? I'd suggest using just `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Cookies")]` and specify that your cookie authentication scheme setup in the startup is called "Cookies".

Comment: `AuthorizeEnumAttribute` is an attribute I created. It is basically to be able to pass an enum instead of the role names. But I think `AuthenticationSchemes = "Cookies")` is the default. I have developed other .NET Core app and I only use [Authorize] attribute. The difference with this project is that the modules are in different assembles.

Comment: Then please post the code of `AuthorizeEnumAttribute`. It's derived from `AuthorizeAttribute`, eh?

Comment: @SNBS I edited the question to use just `[Authorize]` since the same happens. I had not added the code of my custom attributre before because it is not the cause of the problem. That custom attribute is just an inheritted class from `AuthorizeAttribute`. I am wondering what happened when a secured action is loaded and when the redirect should occur. I need to do some kind of tracing to determine what condition is occuring so that no redirection is performed.

Comment: I've found out ([AI responses](https://www.perplexity.ai/search/ecc26520-17b3-4cf1-b9a3-8e1f7edd8d98?s=c), see the last and second last responses) that the behavior on lack of authentication is configured in the authentication scheme, and the default behavior I suspect is just returning 401. That's why you should try specifying `AuthenticationSchemes = "Cookies"`, so that the implementation of the "Cookies" scheme reads the login page URL from `Web.config` and redirects the user instead of returning 401. Don't forget to use `AddAuthentication("Cookies")` instead of just `AddAuthentication()`.

Comment: @SNBS I have used this instead: `services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` and it works. The protected action redirects to Login page, however, API calls are also redirected to Login page, even when they are authenticated using bearer token. How can I have both Cookie and token based authentication?

Comment: I should add `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` to the api controller instead of just `Authorize`. I can create a new custom attribute to set the authentication scheme, but,. is there a setting to do this?

Comment: "is there a setting to do this" — what do you mean?

Comment: `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` works yes?

Comment: @SNBS I created an `ApiAuthorizeAttribute` but I was wondering if I could avoid that by setting some option when configuring the service.